# Counting the total number of selected elements in a plugin.

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to count the total number of times a selected element is present in a html document , i have to do this in a Jquery plugin :

so say i select all images in the html doc. like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').randomize();
});
```

now in the Jquery plugin , how do i count the total number of times the img occurs in the html document ? also note that i want always be selecting an img , it might be any other html element or class or id .

so i wrote the following code in the plugin :

```
   var count = 0;
    $(this).each(function(){
            count++;
    });
```

now this does the job but somehow looks dirty to me , i would prefer writing a function that does the counting , so i tried that too :

```
    function number_of_image(){
          $(this).each(function(){
            count++;
        }); 
        return count;
    };
```

i somehow can't get `$(this)` to point to the current selected element (in this case 'img').

i tried one more thing and thats i tried storing `$(this)` in a variable as a global declaration :

var current = $(this);

and then use current like this :

```
    function number_of_image(){
          current.each(function(){
            count++;
        }); 
        return count;
    };
```

somehow this too does't do the job , in either of the above to cases i have no idea where EXACTLY $(this) is pointing too .

So coming back to the question :

How do i write a function that counts the number of selected Elements ?? Please be as elaborate with your explanation as possible , i am a newbie :D

Thank you .

Comment: @RahulDesai Jst going through ur answer , thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said inside a plugin, your code will have to be slightly different to what @rahul has suggested, but yes you will have to pass $(this) as a parameter to the `number_of_image()` function.

The code will look something as follows :

```
        function number_of_image(current){
              $(current).each(function(){
                count++;
            }); 
            return count;
        };
```

Now you can call the function as follows or console.log it and check the results :

```
console.log(number_of_image($(this)));
```

or even store it in a variable, which I guess is what you're trying to do, if you're using it in a plugin :

```
var storage = number_of_image($(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `$('img')` to `number_of_image()` for your code to work.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var count = 0;

function number_of_image(image){
  $(image).each(function(){
    count++;
  }); 
  alert(count);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  number_of_image($('img'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 3 sample images -->
<img src="http://pbltech.org/wiki/images/e/e6/Sample.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.officeshop.co.nz/shop/494-664-large/account-overdue-dixon-stamp.jpg" />
<img src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/thumb_COLOURBOX10334787.jpg" />
```